# How to fetch attribute values of android widget in java?

Tags: android, user-interface, attributes, get

I have extended Android's Button class and I would like to access some of the attribute values being set in the XML file through java code, for example, padding, gravity. Let me know how to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor you get an [AttributeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html) and with [obtainStyledAttributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#obtainStyledAttributes%28int%5B%5D%29) you can access attributes from xml but some of these are private and not accessible through the sdk. also have a look at the source code from [TextView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView) especially the constructor starting @line 311.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. 
It is not exacty the prettiest thing in the world, but it should work.

```
 public class TestLayout extends LinearLayout {
        private static final String ANDROID_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

        // XXX: This is defined in
        // com.android.interal.R.styleable.LinearLayout_*** but are not accessible
        // in the SDK :(
        private static final String ORIENTATION_ATTRIBUTE = "orientation";

        public SignUpHeaderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            initialize(attrs);
        }

        private void initialize(AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (!isSet(attrs, ORIENTATION_ATTRIBUTE)) {
                setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            }
        }

        private boolean isSet(AttributeSet attrs, String attribute) {
            return attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NAMESPACE, attribute, -1) != -1;
        }

    }
```